# Aggregate Same Column, Different Tables

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have the following schema:

**table_1**
id, updated_at

**table_2**
id, updated_at

**table_3**
id, updated_at

and in total there are about 12 tables that I want to get the *updated_at* column and determine the MAX() aggregate value from all of them, based on a single *id* value.

How would I set up this query?

Comment: Same `id` across several tables?  Ugh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the maximum `updated_at` for a given `id` from each table, combine the results into one row set and then get the maximum from it

```
SELECT
  MAX(updated_at)
FROM
  (
    SELECT MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM table1 WHERE id = @param_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM table2 WHERE id = @param_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM table3 WHERE id = @param_id
    UNION ALL
    ...
  ) AS derived
;
```

This is much more efficient then combining the tables first and then filtering and aggregating the combined set, even though the code would look simpler that way.

This method can also benefit from an index on `(id, udpated_at)` in each table, while probably no index would help if you decided to combine whole tables first.

Answer (score 0):

First select and `union` all table data
and then use `max()` with `group by id`

```
select max(t.updated_at) from(
  select id,updated_at from table1
  union
  select id,updated_at from table2
  union
  select id,updated_at from table3
  union
  select id,updated_at from table4
) as t group by t.id;
```